# Display specific data in a table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an angular project where I have a table I am populating from an api.
In the table there is a column status with three values: 1- Open, 2- Released, 3- Rejected.
displayed with,
`<td>{{working_period.status}}</td>`
Here's pic of the table
Image
What I want is a pipe to display only one status. E.g Only 1- open

How can I go about creating such a pipe, and is it the best solution?

I am newbie in ng7. In case of clarification let me know...please forgive my grammar.

**Edit**
my dashboard.component.html

```
 <table class="table">
             <thead><th>Mitarbeiter</th><th>Einsatz</th><th>Eingangsdatum</th><th>Zeitraum</th><th>Status</th></thead>
             <tr *ngFor="let working_period of customers"> ...... <td>{{working_period.status}}</td></tr>
           </table>
```

My dashboard.component.ts

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { NgbProgressbarConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {pipe, of, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivityReportsService } from '../../services/activity-reports.service';
import { CustomerLoginService } from '../../services/customer-login.service';
import {Customer, CustomerResponce} from '../../_models/customer';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './dashboard1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard1.component.css']
})

export class Dashboard1Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  currentUser: Customer;
  currentUserSubscription: Subscription;
  customers: Customer[] = [];
  constructor(
    private customerloginservice: CustomerLoginService,
    private activityreportservice: ActivityReportsService
  ) {
    this.currentUserSubscription = this.customerloginservice.currentUser.subscribe(customer => {
      this.currentUser = customer;
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAllReports();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.currentUserSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
  private  loadAllReports() {
    this.activityreportservice.getAll().subscribe((customers: CustomerResponce) => {
      console.log(customers);
      this.customers = customers.working_periods;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code and data structure you're working with to help with the best output concepts.

Comment: @BenRacicot, I have just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (SearchPipe.pipe.ts)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'searchFilter'
})

// Pipe to implement a search filter basd on input

export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], searchTerm: string): any[] {
        if (!items) { return []; }
        return items.filter((val) => {
            return val.status === searchTerm;
        });
    }
}
```

in HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Mitarbeiter</th>
        <th>Einsatz</th>
        <th>Eingangsdatum</th>
        <th>Zeitraum</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor="let working_period of customers | searchFilter:'open'"> ......
        <td>{{working_period.status}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do I need toLowerCase()?

Comment: @KelvinCayman,  this is a generic filter pipe, you can use for example with textfield (search input), so text field's value can be  'open',  'Open',  'OPEN' ...etc

Comment: Thanks @Ghoul Ahmed. But I want to display only status 1...not to search.

Answer (score 0):

Please create 1 function like FilterStatusData(filterstatus) which called after api get response.

In FilterStatusData modify data using loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it without using a pipe (Dashboard1Component)

```
this.customers = customers.working_periods.filter(res=>res.status==='open');
```